# Laplace transform of a gaussian function?

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I find the Laplace transform of this Gaussian function $f(t)=\sqrt{t}e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$.
I have from a table that $L\Big[{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-\frac{a^2}{4t}}}\Big ]=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}e^{-a\sqrt{s}}$ for a Gaussian Normal Distribution.
If I set $a=2$ then the formula are alike apart for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LT you seek may be written as

$$\begin{align} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, \sqrt{t} \, e^{-1/t} e^{-s t} &= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} du \, u^2 \, e^{-(s u^2+1/u^2)} \\ &= 2 e^{2 \sqrt{s}} \int_0^{\infty} du \, u^2 \, e^{-\left (\sqrt{s} u + 1/u \right )^2} \\  \end{align}$$

Sub $v=\sqrt{s} u+1/u$, which implies two branches of the integration region:

$$u = \frac1{2 \sqrt{s}} \left (v \pm \sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}} \right ) $$
$$du = \frac1{2 \sqrt{s}} \left (1 \pm \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}}} \right ) dv$$

Thus, the LT we seek may be written as

$$e^{2 \sqrt{s}} \int_{\infty}^{2 s^{1/4}} dv \frac1{\sqrt{s}} \left (1 - \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}}} \right ) \left (\frac{v - \sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}}}{2 \sqrt{s}} \right )^2 e^{-v^2} \\ + e^{2 \sqrt{s}} \int_{2 s^{1/4}}^{\infty} dv \frac1{\sqrt{s}} \left (1 + \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}}} \right ) \left (\frac{v + \sqrt{v^2-4 \sqrt{s}}}{2 \sqrt{s}} \right )^2 e^{-v^2} $$

This looks horrendous but it simplifies considerably.  Further, if we sub $v=2 s^{1/4} \cosh{w}$ and perform a little algebra, we get for the LT:

$$2 s^{-3/4} e^{-2 \sqrt{s}} \int_0^{\infty} dw \, \cosh{w} (1+4 \sinh^2{w}) e^{-4 \sqrt{s} \sinh^2{w}}$$

which again simplifies considerably to

$$2 s^{-3/4} e^{-2 \sqrt{s}} \int_0^{\infty} dp \, (1+4 p^2) e^{-4 \sqrt{s} p^2} $$

And now we are at a standard integral for which no further elaboration should be needed.  The result we seek is

> $$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, \sqrt{t} \, e^{-1/t} \, e^{-s t} = \frac12 \sqrt{\pi} e^{-2 \sqrt{s}} \left (s^{-3/2} +2 s^{-1}  \right ) $$

Comment: I think that in the final result you should replace $s^{-1/2}$ with $s^{-1}$. Am I right?

Comment: please use the standard notation $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$

Comment: @user1952009: No.

Comment: @RobertZ: Yes, good catch.  Thanks.

Comment: use the same notation as everybody, that's how maths notation work

Comment: the problem is that you know the standard maths notations, so, as the teacher you pretend to be when answering those questions, you should use the standard notations

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$. Then $f(t)=tg(t)$.

Now, by the [frequency-domain derivative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform, 
$$L(f(t))=L(tg(t))=-\frac{d}{ds}(L(g)(s))
=-\frac{d}{ds}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}e^{-2\sqrt{s}}\right)
\\=
-\sqrt{\pi}\left(-\frac{s^{-3/2}e^{-2\sqrt{s}}}{2}+s^{-1/2}\cdot\frac{-2e^{-2\sqrt{s}}}{2\sqrt{s}})\right)
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} e^{-2 \sqrt{s}}}{2} \left (s^{-3/2} +2 s^{-1}  \right ).$$

Comment: Now I see it, my mistake was to take the derivative of g first.

Comment: @S.n if $F(s) = \int_a^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ and everything converges nicely, then $F'(s) =\int_a^\infty f(t)(-t) e^{-st}dt$ you should remember that

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\root{t}\expo{-1/t}
\expo{-st}\dd t}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{st\ \mapsto\ t}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over s^{3/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-t - {\bracks{\color{red}{2\root{s}}}^{2} \over 4t}}\,
{\dd t \over t^{\color{red}{-3/2} + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over s^{3/2}}\bracks{\on{K}_{\color{red}{-3/2}}\,\pars{\color{red}{2\root{s}}} \over \pars{1/2}\pars{\color{red}{2\root{s}}/2}^{\color{red}{-3/2}}} =
{2 \over s^{3/4}}\on{K}_{3/2}\,\pars{2\root{s}}
\end{align}

See [this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10). $\ds{\on{K}_{\nu}}$ is a *Modified Bessel Function*. Note that $\ds{\on{K}_{\nu}\pars{z} = \on{K}_{-\nu}\pars{z}}$

However, $\ds{K_{3/2}\pars{z} = \root{\pi \over 2}\expo{-z}\
{z + 1 \over z^{3/2}}}$. See [${\bf\color{black}{10.2.17}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_444.htm).

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\root{t}\expo{-1/t}
\expo{-st}\dd t} =
{2 \over s^{3/4}}\bracks{\root{\pi \over 2}\expo{-2\root{s}}
{2\root{s} + 1 \over \pars{2\root{s}}^{3/2}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{{\root{\pi} \over 2}\pars{s^{-3/2} + 2s^{-1}}\expo{-2\root{s}}} \\ &
\end{align}